# Rails Simple Captcha not going over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx, captcha

I'm using the `simple_captcha2` gem for authentication with Rails and have it working fine in development but the captcha image/code is not going over the SSL layer in production so the image is not rendering within the captcha form. I set up OpenSSL using this [letsencrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial for multiple domains and it's worked fine for everything but `simple_captcha2`.

Here is the error output from Firefox:

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://example.com/simple_captcha?code=f987a2c87ea145419d79a00d6a257df701e2bea8&time=1465962694" on a secure page
```

Comment: Change **http** to **https** and it should work fine.

Comment: Where would one change that if they're using simple_captcha2, like somewhere in the source for the gem itself?

Comment: I searched the codebase on Github and didn't find any matches for that URL. So it seems to not be generated by the gem directly (though it could be one of it's dependencies). Like has been said, change `http://anrcho.com` to `https://anrcho.com` somehow and it should work.

Comment: I just found where it's building the URL [here](https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha/blob/master/lib/simple_captcha/view.rb) but I'm not sure if I should actually edit the source for the gem or if there's a better route available.

Comment: Looks like the code should use https if the request's protocol matches https (per the code [here](https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha/blob/master/lib/simple_captcha/view.rb#L86)). How are you running your rails app (e.g. puma behind nginx proxy)? Often, you need a directive in nginx to forward the protocol over the proxy so that rails is aware the request is https. If you can provide some more detail, I (or someone else) can probably help you get this answered.

Comment: I'm using nginx with unicorn and I think the problem has something to do with Rails `request.protocol` that keeps returning `http` when the URL clearly has https.

Comment: As far as rails being aware the request is https, I just found this question where the person seems to have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223470/nginx-can-not-forward-the-request-protocol-correctly-to-upstream

Comment: Okay so I changed my nginx config file so that https is being forwarded to rails and the page is loading fine now with no insecure content but the captcha image is still not loading.

Comment: It's working now after installing imagemagick. The assistance was much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following lines (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223470/nginx-can-not-forward-the-request-protocol-correctly-to-upstream)) to my `nginx.conf` solved the issue of `request.protocol` returning the wrong protocol:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
```

As far as the captcha image not loading, whether as secure or insecure content, `imagemagick` has to be installed.