# Nginx can not forward the request protocol correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I am in development rails 4.0.4 website, and serving via nginx and unicorn.
I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223470/nginx-can-not-forward-the-request-protocol-correctly-to-upstream) and [here](https://gist.github.com/goldenprovider/94c474ca94e64c3f40677331c323e132) is my nginx config.
But I still get `request.ssl?` false.
Anyone please help me.

Comment: Why are you server content on both http and https? Disable the http block for now and then test the https part just to isolate the issue

Comment: hi, opsworks does health check and it requires only http, not https.